# PostgreSQL Trigger on Insert or Update

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, constraints

I have two tables. I want to create a trigger on the `car` table which will insert or delete on the `fuel` table depending on a certain value.

**Car**

```
id - SERIAL
fuel - BOOLEAN
```

**Fuel**

```
car_id -  INTEGER
```

I am not including any row data as the description of the trigger does not need it.

Basically, I want to create a trigger on the `Car` table that:

- Runs on an insert or update.
- Inserts `Car.id` into `Fuel` table if `Car.fuel is true`.
- If `Car.fuel is false`, the trigger should delete all rows in the `Fuel` table where `Fuel.car_id = Car.id`.

How would I do this?

EDIT: To clarify I am using Postgres

Comment: Refer http://plsql-tutorial.com/plsql-triggers.htm

Comment: I always assumed PSQL was the identifier for Postgres.. But yea I am using postgres :)

Comment: `psql` is mostly short for Postgres, that's true. But it could also be a typo meaning `PL/PSQL` (which is Oracle's procedural language). Postgres' procedural language is called `PL/pgSQL`

Comment: There are many issues to handle. What should trigger do if there is upadate, that doesn't change value of "fuel". What should it do if id is changed? What should be done if pre, or post update, fuel is null?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you haven't mentioned the RDBMS, I assume it is Oracle. Below is the trigger. If you are using another RDBMS, tweak the code to fit the syntax.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_CAR
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON CAR
   FOR EACH ROW

   BEGIN

     IF :new.FUEL THEN
       INSERT INTO FUEL (CAR_ID) VALUES (:new.ID);
     ELSE
       DELETE FROM FUEL WHERE CAR_ID = :new.ID;
     END IF;
   END;
```

Comment: I don't think `IF :new.FUEL THEN` will work in Oracle as it does not have a BOOLEAN **SQL** datatype (only PL/SQL has). So the `:NEW` record can not have a boolean column. I actually think Ozzy is using Postgres (`psql` is Postgres' command line tool)